# Git push branch from different checked out branch

Tags: git, push

Can you 'git push origin branch1' while you have branch2 checked out?

```
git checkout branch1
git commit -am 'changes 1'
git checkout branch2
git commit -am 'changes 2'
git push origin branch1
```

Will that only push branch1 to the remote repo or will branch2 changes be pushed?

Answer (score 1):

```
git push <repository> <refspec>
```

Will only push the specified refs to the remote specified. In the case where `<refspec>` is a branch name, only that remote branch will be updated.

If `<refspec>` is not specified, the behavior is controlled by the `push.default` configuration variable.

More information is available on the [git-push(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) and [git-config(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) man pages.

Comment: So it doesn't matter what branch you currently have checked out?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what push.default is configured to.  If you `git config push.default = matching` and you have remote branches branch1 and branch2, yes both branch1 and branch2 will be push.

Final answer is to use `-n` to see what would happen without actually pushing:

```
git push -n
```